# Function to translate end coordinates of a line

Tags: java, android, math, geometry, algebra

I have two points at the end of a line.
I need to get the end coordinates of a translation of this line.
The translation will be a parallel line that is a distance d from the original line.
here is an image of what i need:

[image]

So I need a function that I can pass these two points and the distance and get the two new coordinates in returns.
I have been stuck on this problem for a while. Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks you!

Comment: Which direction will the line be projected if `distance` is positive? negative?

Comment: This translation is ambiguous without another direction.  There are an infinite number of lines that are distance `d` away from and parallel to the line.

Comment: I want it to be a line segment of the same length and parallel to the original. and If you were to draw a line between the old and new points, it should form a perpendicular line with the original line. Im not sure if that is clear.  I want the line seen in the image though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new co-ordinates will be the resulting vector of

> distance **d** multiplied by **normalized vector** of which direction it's moving, added to the **original vector** point.

**EDIT:**

Given the two points of the line, you will need to calculate the normal of the vector joining these points. [Information on that is here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243614/how-do-i-calculate-the-normal-vector-of-a-line-segment)

**Normalise** this vector, multiply by **d**, add to each **point**.

Comment: After playing with it for a bit I figured it out!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the vector (x2-x1,y2-y1). This is a vector in the direction of your line. A normal vector is then given by

```
    (-(y2-y1),-(x2-x1)) = (y1-y2,x1-x2).
```

Divide this vector by its size to get the unit vector in the direction you want

```
    A = (y1-y2,x1-x2)/|(y1-y2,x1-x2)|
```

Now given your distance `d` your translated point will be given by

```
    NewPoint = OldPoint + d * A
```