# Intersection between Rectangle and a Circle sector in libgdx

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, intersection

I am programming a game using libgdx. For the Enemies i want to write a simple AI. This AI should track the Player if he was in the field of Vision once. The field of Vision is a circle sector or 2d cone. What would be the most efficient way to reach this? I have allready read the following:
[Point in circle sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652518/efficiently-find-points-inside-a-circle-sector)

I could use this with every Corner Point of my Player but i also have the field of Vision given with direction and angle (sector between `direction - angle/2` to `direction + angle/2`).
The angle won't be over 180 (as this would be a problem for the algorithm). Would it be a Problem to calculate the Vectors for start and end of sector for every enemie in the game? What would be the best solution and how can i calculate the Vectors out of the given direction and angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the solution described in the linked post, but you have to convert your angles to vectors by calculating the sine and cosine of `dir +/- angle/2`. The linked solution talks about integer arithmetic, but your vectors will be floats:

```
arm1 = [cos(d - 0.5 * a), sin(d - 0.5 * a)]
arm2 = [cos(d + 0.5 * a), sin(d + 0.5 * a)]
```

The arguments to `cos` and `sin` are in radians. An angle of zero points in the x direction, i.e. east in a traditional Cartesian system.

In order not to do unecessary work, you should check the easy things first.

I would do a simple box check before checking for intersection with the sector: If all four corner points of your rectangle are outside the square box around the enemy, there is no intersection:

```
if (x0 < x-r && x1 < x-r && x2 < x-r && x3 < x-r) return false;
if (x0 > x+r && x1 > x+r && x2 > x+r && x3 > x+r) return false;
if (y0 < y-r && y1 < y-r && y2 < y-r && y3 < y-r) return false;
if (y0 > y+r && y1 > y+r && y2 > y+r && y3 > y+r) return false;
```

This simple check should rule out many enemies.

Next, check the radius for all four points as described in the linked answer and return false if none of your corner points is within the radius.

It is only now that we have to calculate the vectors with the trig functions. You can do this with the formula given above. If you have the sine and cosine of the enemy and angle already, you can use [addition theoremes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_addition_formulas#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) to speed up vector calculation:

```
# sin_d = sin(d), cos_d = cos(d)
# sin_a = sin(0.5 * a), cos_a = cos(0.5 * a)

arm1 = [cos_d * cos_a + sin_d * sin_a, sin_d * cos_a - cos_d * sin_a]
arm2 = [cos_d * cos_a - sin_d * sin_a, sin_d * cos_a + cos_d * sin_a]
```

The viewing angle is probably a constant for each enemy, so you can precalculate it, and you might already have `cos_d` and `sin_d` precomputed as well.

If you are not concerned with accuracy and don't want to get into radians, you could precompute the sines and cosines for one-degree steps and store them in two arrays of size 360. Then calculating the sine will become a matter of looking up an array, i.e. it will be fast, and you can do all your calculations n degrees. (But take care of wrapping: 5° - 15° should then be 350°, not -10°.)

Comment: Thanks a lot (: I dont Need to be highly accurate as it is only for saying the enemie to track the Player. Just a Little question: Why should i first do the box check and then the radius check? The radius check won't cost much as it is only comparing the square distance between the Centers with the squared radiuses of the Vision field and player(actualy my Player and the enemies are both circles as they can rotate and rotating circles is easier then rotating rectangles :P).
So can i let the box check away without losing Performance?

Comment: @Springrbua: The raduis check might perform better when you don't calculate the square root, you're right. You can easily check this by comparing performances with and without that additional box check.

Comment: I don't use square roots for that (it makes no sense). So i do the radius check and then the ClockWise and counter-ClockWise check.

Comment: Yes, I know that the call to sqrt is superflous here. The linked answer also compared the squares of the radii. I thought that the box check was quicker than calculating the square distance (on a gut feeling no less), but I'm probably wrong and it adds unecessary overhead: just the distance check should be enough.

Comment: @M Oehm I found another possible solution for this: I have the rotation of the enemie, and the angle between the player and the enemie (relative to x-Axis). Couldn't i check, if the angle between them is in a a tollerance area (lets say enemie.getRotation() + 20 >= angle between them >= enemie.getRotation() - 20). And ofc the distance check stays the same. Isn't that easier?

Comment: @Springrbua: Sure, if you have the data already, why not make use of it? Sounds good. But you need the opposite angle, from enemy to player, i.e. angle + 180°. Also, take care of wrapping: If the player is at 5° from the enemy and the enemy looks in direction 355°, he should still be able to see the player, because 355° is the same as -5°.

Comment: @M Oehm oh yes ofc! Yea i will take the angle between enemie and player not player - enemie. This solution came to my mind, when i saw that libgdx Vector2 has method sub, which subtracts 2 vectors and angle, which gives me the angle of the vector. So i can take enemieVector.sub(playerVector).angle() to have the angle between them.