# Clamp angle to arbitrary range

Tags: c++, range, angle

I need a function to clamp an angle (in degrees) into an arbitrary range `[min,max]`. Here are some examples:
[image: Angle range examples]

The colored areas represent the valid angle range.

- In image #1, *ang* should be clamped to *max* (-90)
- In image #2, *ang* should be clamped to *min* (135)
- In image #3, *ang* should be clamped to *min* (135)

This is what I have so far:

```
static float clamp_angle(float ang,float min,float max)
{
    ang = normalize_angle(ang); // normalize_angle transforms angle into [-180,180) range
    min = normalize_angle(min);
    max = normalize_angle(max);
    if(angle_in_range(ang,min,max) == false)
    {
        if(abs(get_angle_difference(ang,min)) < abs(get_angle_difference(ang,max))
            ang = min; // Clamp to min if we're closer to min than max
        else
            ang = max;
    }
    return ang;
}
```

What I'm missing is the function `angle_in_range` (`true` if the angle is within the range, otherwise `false`).
What would be the simplest way of determining whether the angle is within the range or not?

Comment: This sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652518/efficiently-find-points-inside-a-circle-sector ? At least the math requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can normalize angles in such a way that ang become 0 and min and max is mapped to [-180; 180). Then you can check if angle is in provided range like this:

```
float clamp_angle(const float ang, const float min, const float max)
{
    float n_min = normalize180(min-ang);
    float n_max = normalize180(max-ang);

    if (n_min <= 0 && n_max >= 0)
    {
        return ang;
    }
    if (abs(n_min) < abs(n_max))
        return min;
    return max;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b071757e67aecbd0)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Assume you use clockwise order.
The distance between min and max in cw order is dist(min, max) = (max - min)mod N
Assume point inside region. Then dist(min,A) + dist(A,max) = dist(min,max). Now you can measure distance between point A, min and max : dist(min, A)= (A - min)modN
dist(A, max)=(max-A)modN. If A outside region, then sum of the distances should be N+dist(min, max), if inside it should be equal dist(min,max)

In your case N = 360, all values lies in [0,360)

Edit: In most languages behavior of (-x)modX is undefined, so you should manually convert -x to positive number e.g. (-x + X)modX where x lies in [0,X)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clamp the angle so that it stays within the range but it wraps around when it reaches max or min (instead of clipping to the limits) then you could use this fairly simple function I worte using python:

```
def clamp_to_range(value, min, max):
     return (value % (max - min)) + min
```

It behaves like this:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 30): print("|{:<30}|{:<30}|".format(" "*(clamp_to_range(i, 4, 15)) + "♥", " "*i + "♥"))
...
|    ♥                         |♥                             |
|     ♥                        | ♥                            |
|      ♥                       |  ♥                           |
|       ♥                      |   ♥                          |
|        ♥                     |    ♥                         |
|         ♥                    |     ♥                        |
|          ♥                   |      ♥                       |
|           ♥                  |       ♥                      |
|            ♥                 |        ♥                     |
|             ♥                |         ♥                    |
|              ♥               |          ♥                   |
|    ♥                         |           ♥                  |
|     ♥                        |            ♥                 |
|      ♥                       |             ♥                |
|       ♥                      |              ♥               |
|        ♥                     |               ♥              |
|         ♥                    |                ♥             |
|          ♥                   |                 ♥            |
|           ♥                  |                  ♥           |
|            ♥                 |                   ♥          |
|             ♥                |                    ♥         |
|              ♥               |                     ♥        |
|    ♥                         |                      ♥       |
|     ♥                        |                       ♥      |
|      ♥                       |                        ♥     |
|       ♥                      |                         ♥    |
|        ♥                     |                          ♥   |
|         ♥                    |                           ♥  |
|          ♥                   |                            ♥ |
|           ♥                  |                             ♥|
```

as I mentioned, it wraps around. If you instead want to clip the value to the specified limits, you can use this function:

```
def clip_to_range(value, min_, max_):  # underscores added to avoid name collisions
     return min(max_, max(value, min_))
```

In this case this will happen:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 30): print("|{:<30}|{:<30}|".format(" "*clip_to_range(i, 4, 15) + "♥", " "*i + "♥"))
...
|    ♥                         |♥                             |
|    ♥                         | ♥                            |
|    ♥                         |  ♥                           |
|    ♥                         |   ♥                          |
|    ♥                         |    ♥                         |
|     ♥                        |     ♥                        |
|      ♥                       |      ♥                       |
|       ♥                      |       ♥                      |
|        ♥                     |        ♥                     |
|         ♥                    |         ♥                    |
|          ♥                   |          ♥                   |
|           ♥                  |           ♥                  |
|            ♥                 |            ♥                 |
|             ♥                |             ♥                |
|              ♥               |              ♥               |
|               ♥              |               ♥              |
|               ♥              |                ♥             |
|               ♥              |                 ♥            |
|               ♥              |                  ♥           |
|               ♥              |                   ♥          |
|               ♥              |                    ♥         |
|               ♥              |                     ♥        |
|               ♥              |                      ♥       |
|               ♥              |                       ♥      |
|               ♥              |                        ♥     |
|               ♥              |                         ♥    |
|               ♥              |                          ♥   |
|               ♥              |                           ♥  |
|               ♥              |                            ♥ |
|               ♥              |                             ♥|
```

A C analog to the `clamp_to_range` function would look like this:

```
#include <math.h>

float clampInRange(float value, float min, float max)
{
    return fmod(value, max - min) + min;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you subtract the "min" from value before the modulo operation? That is  return (value - min_val) % (max_val - min_val)) + min_val. 
On another note: you SHOULD NOT use min or max as variable names, because min and max are built-in python functions