# How to find the normal vector at a point on a curve in MatLab

Tags: matlab, gradient, curve, normals

I have a curve and I want to find the normal vector at a given point on this curve, later I have to find the dot product of this normal vector with another vector.

I tried the gradient function of MatLab, but I guess it doesnt work when we need to find the gradient at a specific point still I am not sure if I am wrong.

Please guide me how can I achieve this in MatLab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Important: is this an analytic curve, i.e., do you have an equation to generate it? Or is obtained from data.

Comment: Can you share your Matlab code - what you have so far? That will make it easier to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: @Horchler - Ya I have and equation to generate it.The MatLab code is very long, I dont think it will be convenient to go through such a long code.

Answer (score 7):

Using the explanation from this [incredible SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243614/how-do-i-calculate-the-normal-vector-of-a-line-segment):

> if we define dx=x2-x1 and dy=y2-y1, then the normals are (-dy, dx) and (dy, -dx).

Here's an example using an analytic curve of `y = x^2`

```
x = 0:0.1:1;
y = x.*x;
dy = gradient(y);
dx = gradient(x);
quiver(x,y,-dy,dx)
hold on; plot( x, y)
```

which gives:

[image: Quiver]

PS:
Sorry about the tangential example!!!  Got in a hurry.  Thanks to Schorsch and Shawn314!

Comment: Aren't these tangential vectors and not normal vectors?

Comment: My thoughts exactly Schorsch

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but going back to Calculus 1 might be a pretty viable option here. Calculate derivative of curve at your point, find normal to that, I think if you were to just google "Matlab deriviate" and "calculate normal to derivative" you should be good

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but for any1 that would be the first option to try. Nevertheless, it is not what I want. anyways thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the other answer was really good, and I know there are a lot of FEX entries as well which I think calculate it for 2-d and 3-d curves so those might be worth checking out as well, best of luck!