# How to choose normal vector (2d) that point to inside any convex polygon?

Tags: math, vector, geometry

Okay, I have a programming assignment, cyrus-beck algorithm. This algorithm needs `normal vector` that point to inside any convex polygon.

Now i just in checking function, checks whether the point is inside or outside the edge.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243614/how-do-i-calculate-the-normal-vector-of-a-line-segment/1243676#1243676) tell me how to calculate the normal vector, but it gives me two results. and I still struggling to choose which vector should I use.

what is criteria of normal vector that point to inside the polygon?

Is there any a formula / way to calculate normal (point to inside) for any edge in polygon?

Please go easy with the explanation, because I don't really understand about vector and math stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the n points p[] in clockwise order, then to get the inward pointing normal to an edge between points p[i] and p[i+1] you rotate the vector p[i]->p[i+1] clockwise through 90 degrees. That is:

```
double dx = p[i+1].x - p[i].x; // x component of edge
double dy = p[i+1].y - p[i].y; // y component of edge
double ndx = dy; // x component of normal
double ndy = -dx; // y component of normal
```

(note that the last edge uses p[n-1] and p[0] (in that order)).

If instead you have the points in anticlockwise order, negate both components of n.